# Inno Setup directive "VersionInfoVersion" is invalid

Tags: inno-setup, versioning

In my *.iss installer script I'm passing application version to the VersionInfoVersion param

```
VersionInfoVersion = {#ver}
```

where `{#ver}` is `0.4.0.201801182`

According to [Inno Setup documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_versioninfoversion) format is correct. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Value of [Setup] section directive "VersionInfoVersion" is invalid.
Compile aborted.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the last section of your version.  It appears that each section only supports up to 65,535.  For example:

```
#define ver "0.4.0.65535" ;this works
#define ver "0.4.0.65536" ;this fails
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Thank you for your post. Is this in the official documentation?